# customizing menu layout in joomla

Tags: php, joomla

Hey everyone.  I would like to create a joomla menu but have it display in three columns, like so:

```
+----------+----------+----------+
| item0    |  item1   | item2    |
| item3    |  item4   | item5    |
|  ...     |  ...     |  ...     |
|          |          |          |
```

For the life of me I can't think of a way to do it. Granted, I am fairly new at joomla and php, but this has me stumped. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: While you're still new at it, get rid of Joomla.  Thank me later.

Comment: Just got a job where my boss wants a website done in a PHP-based CMS. Yeah I'm hating joomla. But it seemed the best of the available alternatives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TO anyone who might come across this, I've come up with a hacky solution. Then again, I'm new at this webdev stuff (doing it for ~3 months) so maybe this is typical:

My solution: The menu buttons are to be images, and so I can rely on them being of fixed size. That being said, I specified the width of their containing element, and get them wrapping. As a proof of concept to myself, I've got the following:

```
<div id="example">
  <jdoc:include type="modules" name="menuposn" />
</div>
```

where the menu is rendered in menuposn. I then have this css:

```
div#example{
  width:600px;
  overflow:auto;
}

div#example ul{
  width:600px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
}

div#example ul li{
  width:200px;
  float:left;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0; 
}
```

It works!

Answer (score 0):

Joomla doesn't come with built-in functionality to create such a drop down menu. However, you might want to have a look at these menu plugins:

http://www.onestopjoomla.com/extensions/menu/

Comment: Thanks man. I'll give it a closer look but just a quick glance and it looks like it'll do the job. TY